# Upgrading to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate

New to ubuntu MATE, currently on 17.10 and considering a new install of 18.04.

How well does settings carry over? 
I've adjusted my desktop and theme quite a bit and installed a custom icon package. My /home is on a separate partition that I wouldn't format.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Most things can be copied to your new install. For example your

```
$HOME/.icons
$HOME/.fonts
$HOME/.themes
$HOME/.wallpapers
```

can be copied without problems, and used on your new install.
If the icons are not stored in `$HOME/.icons`, but e.g. `usr/share/icons`, then you will have to copy them from there (mind your permissions!).
Some people also copy over their other `$HOME/.*` directories (e.g. `$HOME/.config`, `$HOME/.local` which holds your panel settings for example), and although that can work well, it might not go without ripples.